# Can't calculate element's size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to calculate width and height of elements, to set precise position in CSS with jQuery, but for some reason calculation for some IDs doesn't work (alert shows 0 or nothing) while working for other IDs and classes. Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#img1").each(function () {
        var maxtop = $('.pattern').outerHeight() - $('#mimg1').outerHeight() - 20,
            maxleft = $('.pattern').outerWidth() - $('#mimg1').outerWidth() - 20,
            randomtop = getRandomInt(20, maxtop),
            randomleft = getRandomInt(20, maxleft),
            randomzindex = getRandomInt(1, 30);

        $(this).css({
            "top": randomtop,
            "left": randomleft,
            "z-index": randomzindex
        });
    });


    $("#img13").each(function () {
        var maxtop = $('.pattern').outerHeight() - $('#mimg13').outerHeight() - 20,
            maxleft = $('.pattern').outerWidth() - $('#mimg13').outerWidth() - 20,
            randomtop = getRandomInt(20, maxtop),
            randomleft = getRandomInt(20, maxleft),
            randomzindex = getRandomInt(1, 30);

            alert ($('#mimg13').outerHeight());

        $(this).css({
            "top": randomtop,
            "left": randomleft,
            "z-index": randomzindex
        });
    });

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
html {width:100vw; height:100vh;}
body {margin:0; width:100vw; height:100vh; overflow:hidden;}
.pattern {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
.drag {overflow: visible; padding-bottom: 0px; cursor: move; position: absolute;}
.mood-img {position:absolute; display:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="pattern-2">

<div class="pattern"></div>

<div id="img1" class="drag mood-img">
    <img class="shadow moodimg1" src="mood/brick-mood-1.png">
    <span class="mood-name shadow">
        <nobr>A. Brickwork I</nobr> 
    </span>
</div>

<div id="img13" class="drag mood-img">
    <img id="moodimg13" class="shadow moodimg" src="mood/brick-graphic-4.png">
    <span class="mood-name shadow">
        <nobr>6. Untitled</nobr><br>
        <small>digital</small>  
    </span>
</div>
</body>
```

I have tried lot of different options but none of them worked and the problem is always (as it seems) is that JS doesn't calculate elements' sizes, so positions are also calculated wrong.

And also may be there's some more simple way to make all these calculation, cause I have 13 elements with different IDs (from img1 to img13 and from mimg1 to mimg13. May be I could use JS to get IDs by itself, with no need for me to write all IDs into JS?

**IDEA**

I have a page with a few div elements, one of them is visible, others are set to `display:none`. When particular span element is clicked, JS sets certain hidden `div` visible, changing its CSS to `display:block`. The `div` I have this problem with at first was an invisible container for several other divs with images and text elements and I wanted to position these contained elements against the container div (which had `width` and `height` set to 0 and `margin` `top` and `left` set to `50%`) with `margin-top` and `margin-left`. Then I set the container to have `100%` `width` and `height` and tried to position container's content with `top` and `left`. Then I removed the container and set its former inner elements to have `position:absolute` and tried to still position it with `top` and `left` properties calculated and set with jQuery. Actually those elements are images with some pop-up text, which should be randomly placed all over the page (`overflow:hidden`), and have `z-index` set randomly as well. I've spent three days trying to find the solution, but got no result — either it's not working at all (elements are placed all on top of one another in the same position (top left corner) either calculations are done wrong and some (or all) divs are positioned out of the page which creates scroll or hiding images when overflow is hidden. Hope I'm explaining it fine, so anyone could be able to understand what have I wanted to do.

Comment: Are you calling the javascript after the html? (At the bottom of the body element?).

Comment: You could use something like `for(var i = 1; i <= 13; i++){$('#img'+i)...}` to select your images and save you writing 13 different selectors out by hand

Comment: @gaynorvader, can you make a jsfiddle with that? I don't understand how to use it within my js, because I need to calculate 13 different sets of CSS values for 13 different elements.

Comment: Here's roughly what I was talking about. This would probably be better done with a `float: left`, but I assume you have a reason for wanting to do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/zHEz5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calculating dimensions on page load - `$(document).ready(...` but unfortunately it doesn't mean the images are ready at this point. It's a common issue.
Since you already have your images wrapped with `.each` function, simply replace it with the `load` event handler

```
$("#img1").on('load', function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all, may be I'm doing something wrong... Can you please take a look at the original page where I have this problem, it's too complex to put it into jsfiddle — http://thelocalgenius.com/patterns/brick-wall-classics/

Comment: Change the selector to `#mimg1`, so it should be `$('#mimg1').on('load', ...`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/iLIWOfa/2/edit

If the CSS of a parent element of a image is `display: none`, the image is not loaded and there is no width or height.

Just set `opacity: 0` instead.

Comment: If I use the opacity instead of display, then the transparent elements would cover the other clickable content of the page, wouldn't they?

Comment: Even if I remove display:none, alert shows nothing (empty alert) and the calculation is wrong anyway.

Comment: Just do like I did on the jsbin

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uvaRAfiB/1/edit?html,css,js,output Try to click buttons — they are covered with transparent divs with images.

Comment: But how it can be if the layer with higher z-index is over a button? It may be transparent, but how you can click trough it?

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome on Mac and in Firefox on Windows — buttons are unclickable when they're covered with transparent divs, even cursor style is `cursor:move;` as those invisible divs have in CSS.